# Rooting Android

Tags: rooting, root-access, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z

I have problem with rooting Android, I tried various methods (including Kingo, EasyRootTool, and etc.) and none pf them worked.

My device is

> Sony Z **C6602**
>   Android **4.4.4**
>   Build Number **10.5.1.A.0.283**

Any suggestions how to root it?

Comment: I had a experience to root a sony device once, that I was a little bit complicated, so I think it will be necessary to downgrade your device to Android 4.3, then try this method: http://www.teamandroid.com/2014/03/10/root-xperia-z-c6602-c6603-tutorial/

Comment: (I have a Xperia Z too, and I am rooted/unlocked. You **have** to downgrade to 4.3. But if you have not unlocked your bootloader yet, your data is gone either way.) All my knowledge comes from xda-developers.com, so I looked it up there. There is a thread for it: [How to root 10.5.1.A.0.283 / 10.5.1.A.0.292](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z/general/guide-how-to-root-10-5-1-0-283-t2872873) Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download KingRoot for your device and it is safe I'm using it from last 4 years Download from https://kingroot.net/

**NOTE :** You have to connect your phone with internet(It need approx 2MB)

**Installing Process**

Open KingRoot

it will check whether phone is rooted or not.

then click try root button to start rooting

Now wait for the 100% process ,after this your phone is rooted

Hope it will solve your problem...